# Can i use "hire" in this case?

Tags: meaning, usage

I work as a freelance programmer. When my client requests me to build a website for him, I need to collaborate with a designer. 
If I say "hire a freelance designer" in this case, does it sound awkward?
I usually work with a designer for a very short period of time like a week or two, not regularly but occasionally.
When I said I "hired" a designer, someone (who is not a native speaker either) laughed at me and said, "you are not an employer, so you cannot hire someone."

Can anybody tell me if I was wrong to use "hire" in this case? And if I was, then which word can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'hire' is fine as it means
**to employ someone or *pay someone to do a particular job***

You can also hire a consultant - it does not necessarily mean that he/she becomes your employee (in fact, he/she probably doesn't).

You could also say *I found a freelance designer* or *I'm using a freelance designer.*

The Cambridge Dictionary gives other examples where you can hire someone without actually employing them:

*Poor families don't have enough money to hire good lawyers.*

*We hired a magician to entertain the children.*